# Get the txt file into the push() method?

Tags: javascript

Please help me!
    I have Script:

```
var titles =[];
titles.push('I want file txt in here');
```

I can not get the txt file into the titles.push, so I need some help!

```
function readTextFile(){
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", "text.txt", false);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4){
      if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0){
        var allText = rawFile.responseText;
        console.log(allText);
      }
    }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}
```

Comment: you cannot push the file in an array.You can keep the location of the file in the array

Comment: Hi brk! Is there any method to do that? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a text file ready to show so I used what you should be reading about [XMLHttpRequest.responseText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText) you do not want to use `onreadystatechange` but maybe `xhr.onload` I left some `console.log()s` in the code so you can play around with it.

```js
var titles =[];
titles.push('I want file txt in here');

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText', true);
xhr.responseType = 'text';

xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            //console.log(xhr.response);
            //console.log(xhr.responseText);
            
            // not needed but do not want to push the entire page
            // to titles so lets find just one title
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var doc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, "text/html");
            var title = doc.querySelector('h1');
            // console.log(title);
            titles.push(title);
            logTitles();
        }
    }
};

xhr.send(null);

function logTitles() {
    console.log(titles);
};
```